# Azure Service Fabric: Time out error when redeploying background services

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

When I redeployed the background services with the same release or a new release in CI/CD pipeline in VSTS, I got a time out error:

> **Error Details**
>
> Exception occurred: System.TimeoutException
>
> Retrying remove application..
>
> Exception occurred: System.TimeoutException
>
> Retrying remove application..
>
> Exception occurred: System.TimeoutException
>
> Removal of application 'fabric:/Background Service Name' is timing
>   out. This means that the service is stuck in ChangeRole/Close and the
>   shutdown sequence cannot complete. Performing ForceRemove of the
>   application.
>
> [error]Operation timed out.

I observed the above error as background services were running. When I tried to redeploy the background services, the build agent was not able to stop the running task on background services due to the "Deploy Service Fabric Application" task that got the time out error. This was because we  have a 5-min time interval to run the async task in background services during which we got the time out error again and again .

Is there any solution for this problem besides killing the background service on the SFC node manually?

Can we redeploy the background services without impacting the running task which currently runs on the background service?

Comment: This error is very common when you forget to honor the cancellation token provided by SF. Make sure you pass the cancellation token down to any new classes that might lock the process and check if they are being cancelled so that the service can shutdown gracefully.

Comment: I have already used cancellation token in code. As mentioned above, I am getting error in background services because it is continuously running with interval of 5 mins.

Comment: So this might be the problem, your service wait 5 minutes between checks on the cancellation token, instead you should wait in a way that the token is honoured straight after cancelled not 5 minutesates. Something like this could help. `await Task.Delay(1000, token)`

Comment: I have already used the await Task.Delay(1000, token). As I am getting this error only in background services. Because it is continuously running in background(Runasync(CancellationToken)). I have not used OnCloseAsync() because if i will use it then it is meaning less to tell it as bakground services. As I have already explained above that as background services are contineously running because of that build agent are not able to stop the running task and because of that it is not able to unregister the background services because it is in running mode.